# c# for loop is entering without meeting its condition

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, for-loop, exception

So, I have this `for` loop:

```
double spec = 0, tot = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < omega_algo.Length; i++)
{
      if (omega_algo[i] > 0)
          spec = Math.Sqrt(omega_algo[i]);
      else
          spec = 0;
      tot += spec;
 }
```

Where **`myArray.Length = 50`**.
I get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` while debugging and see that **`i`** is **`50`**.

So, the `for` loop is entering when it shouldn't ( **`i < myArray.Length`** is `false` )!

This exception only occurrs ocasionally, which makes it even more weird.

Does someone have an explanation/fix for this? Am I missing something or could this be a weird Visual Studio bug?

**EDIT:**
I've edited the for loop to show the code.
No **i** is being incremented and **omega_algo** array is not changing at all.

Comment: try `for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length - 1; i++)`

Comment: Are incrementing value of `i` anywhere else in the loop? Are you removing any items from the array inside the loop. I tried your code and it worked perferctly without any issue.

Comment: @NezirYürekli: that's exactly what OP is saying - he wants to know how/why he gets an exception when the loop condition is (i < Length) - so should not enter when i is 50

Comment: You might have accidentally incremented value of i inside your for loop. Please go through your loop body. If not that may be Visual Studio bug.

Comment: Can you show all of your code - or at least a cut down version that demonstrates your problem because it looks as if this code is correct.

Comment: Can you post the code that is inside your for loop ? Either C# is broken and is allowing Falses to become Trues, either you are incrementing the value of i inside your loop, before getting to your array.

Comment: Can you show the *real* code that accesses that `myArray` or `i`? Are you maybe resizing that array or changing the value of `i`?

Comment: Are you by chance accessing another array in your for loop that doesn't have the same number of indices as `omega_algo`?

Comment: Sample edited to show real code. My problem is the random occurrences of this exception. Most of the times works as expected. I will try @Tichau 's suggestion of locking the array. There should only be one thread accessing this part of the code, but I may be overlooking this somewhere.

Comment: @DrewKennedy No, I only access omega_algo there...

Comment: If the error pops up again, please provide a screenshot showing the error message, and where it happened.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Based on the comments below, I wrote a sample app, and your code should work as is.

If your array really does have a length of 50, then the value of `i` will never be 50. The only way this would be possible is if you are changing the value of `i` inside the loop.

Can you provide more code to show some context of how/where this is being used? How the array is being defined etc?

Comment: But then `myArray[49]` will be skipped, in all cases except when the error happens.

Comment: @Guy Kempsell  sample edited! That's my problem, i should never be 50 inside the for loop as it isn't being incremented anywhere...

Comment: I've updated my sample with your code, and the only way I can get this to error is by changing the value of `i` in the Immediate Window

Comment: Actually the variable 'i' will reach 50, then the test fails and the loop ends

Comment: @sam But when 'i' reaches 50, code inside the loop should NOT be executed as the condition fails. It's really weird that the condition is false but the loop runs again... even more weird is that it isn't systematic, it's random..

Answer (score -1):

Your code should work if executed on a single thread. Do you have any thread or asynchrone jobs that are editing the array?

If so, just lock the array before accessing it and before editing it.

```
lock(myArray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
    {
        int someVar = myArray[i]; //this is where exception is thrown when i=50
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Since omega_algo array is not changing at all, this is not a threading issue.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I don't think there's a second thread using this part of the code, but I may be overlooking it. It's worth a shot! Will try this and I will need to run the application several times before the exception randomly occurs. Will report after if it worked!

Comment: -1 Different threads would instantiate different looping variables. Since the source collection is not being changed threading for sure is not the problem

Comment: I was not talking about different threading executing this code, but a thread executing this code, while another one changes the length of the array. It could cause a problem only if the array is not stored in a local variable (a class field for example).
But yes if source collection is not being changed, it is not a threading issue.